# Oracle's set nls_date_format corrupts the date

Tags: oracle, date

I have some code to do replication from an oracle database (not mine) and I'm having problems with the date format.

I'm doing a `set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'` and most fields are returned just fine, eg: `2013-04-03 03:48:46`

However, two columns are being mangled by this ans return some thing like: `0001-03-20 13:00:00`

Now if you squint you can see that it's simply forced the formatting on what looks like a string. I have checked and those columns are of type 'date'.

So what gives? I don't particularly want a one-time solution because this is a general purpose replicator.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "two columns are being mangled"? Can you give us the output of a SELECT with the different NLS settings? Which SQL client are you using to display the data? NLS_DATE_FORMAT *only* affects the display it does not change anything in the data itself.

Comment: Actually I've solved it. What I wasn't aware of is that that table is actually a view (not our db and we've only got limited access). The view was using to_date('dd-mm-yyyy') without a format mask so it was honouring nls_date_format and parsing it in completely the wrong order. Changing the function to read to_date('01-03-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') works fine. Now all I have to do is persuade them to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I meet that problem when I was migrating data from a Java app based database. It is nothing wrong with the date formatting in Oracle. The way I handled it:

```
CREATE TABLE table_dt(d_date DATE);

INSERT INTO table_dt VALUES (TO_DATE('0001-03-20 13:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'));
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM table_dt;
-- 0001-03-20 13:00:00

SELECT  CASE
            WHEN SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'), 1, 1) = '0'
            THEN TO_DATE('2' || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(d_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS'), 2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
            ELSE d_date
        END AS parsed_d_date
FROM    table_dt;
-- 2001-03-20 13:00:00
```

Just to have the hands clear show it to business owner, agree and migrate.